# Media buttons stops working with spotify in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, keyboard, media-buttons

I have Ubuntu 16.04. And the media buttons on my keyboard (previous, play/pause, next) randomly work or don't work with Spotify.

So sometimes when I hit the button they do the job, then they stop working. Sometimes they go back to functioning. Buttons to (dec)increase volume always work (but volume is system-wide, not Spotify).

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old problem with many hacks that works and don't... There's something called `playerctl` that people report working. But I've mostly given up finding a perfect solution and I'm just waiting for Spotify to update in a way that solves everything. In the meantime I have a shortcut for a command that pauses the music:

```
wmctrl -a spotify; sleep 0.2; xdotool key space;sleep 0.2;xdotool key alt+Tab
```

Change `space` to for instance `ctrl+Right` for next song.

This one is funny, but still less work than manually interacting with Spotify. It's however a prerequisite that Alt+Tab works (I know this might differ in say i3 for instance), and that the Spotify window is named "spotify". In my KDE workspace this is done with a `fish` script I borrowed from here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22561/override-the-window-title-for-an-arbitrary-window-in-kde-and-set-a-custom-window

Comment: Interesting option. It can be done simpler than with this fish script though. You can pgrep for Spotify's PID and cross-match it with list wmctrl -l and get the name of the Spotify window like that: `wmctrl -l -p | grep "$(pgrep "spotify")" | cut -d " " -f 8-9999`.  
So the final command would like like this `wmctrl -a "$(wmctrl -l -p | grep "$(pgrep "spotify")" | cut -d " " -f 8-9999)"; sleep 0.05; xdotool key space;sleep 0.3;xdotool key alt+Tab`  
  
Do you know how replace media buttons short cut with this command? I tried with dconf-editor but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's clever. Works great. I'm not sure about Gnome (assumed since you tried dconf-editor), but won't overriding the default mediabuttons' shortcuts with custom ones work? https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/proc_setting-key-shortcut/

Comment: I feel stupid now... :) I just used normal "keyboard" setting from Ubuntu and works well. dconf-editor was a bit too much for this task. Sometimes the whole approach doesn't exactly work, as "alt+tab" sometimes doesn't switch the window back. But it's still better than nothing so I should accept your answer. I guess I will reinstall the whole OS to newest Ubuntu at some point, maybe that will solve the issue.